# Mathematical Ratio among three point lights

Tags: lighting

I was working on a interior model and I want to use the three point light system.And I was wondering if there is any mathematical relation among the lights and their position and strength to produce a better result.(You know some like rim light should be certain distance from character with certain strength and other lights also should be at certain position with specific strength and etc etc).Thanks in advance.

Comment: I never heard of it. BTW I think that all depends on the mood the artist wants to give to the scene.

Comment: You get better at lighting just from playing around.  Once you get a feel for it, and are comfortable with the interface, then lighting comes easy.  It's more a matter of getting to know how the scene will react to the tweaks you do to your lights.  And that comes from practice.  You can look at photographer setups, to see how they light objects, and try to mimic that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such formula, as lighting depends on the intentions of the artist.

Moreover thinking in three point lighting is also quite limiting, Sometimes you just need one light, sometimes you need more than 10 sources...

Some questions to ask yourself are:

What are the characteristics of the object that you want to portray? How is your lighting going to enhance, reveal or suppress them? Where is the main light source coming from? Do you want defined shadows or do you want soft ones? How dark do you need the shadows to be? How is the shadow of an object going to affect others in the scene or how are the shadows of other objects affecting the one you are focusing on? Can the lights affect how you perceive the shape of objects? Should your object be brighter or darker than the background? How would the light help guide the viewer on reading an image? How are the bright and dark areas affecting the overall composition of the image?

There are endless variables, and the history of art going back to cave paintings deal with solutions to particular challenges... Study images you like and think of where the light is coming from and how the the different sources interact.

Try things, experiment with placement, size, intensity and color and you'll find answers according to your taste.